# How to use a hyperlink in a gridview to execute a function in aspx code behind

Tags: gridview, hyperlink, templatefield

How to use a hyperlink in a gridview to execute a function in `aspx` code behind when clicked passing a variable to that function which is some value of a cell within the row the hyperlink exits in.

Example:
HTML Code:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HeaderText" SortExpression="HeaderText">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Hyperlink1" runat="server" Text="Hyperlink1"
                        OnClick="SomeFunction(GridView1.Row.Cells(0).Text)" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

ASP Code Behind:

```
Sub SomeFunction(ByVal sVariable As Object)

       'Do some stuff

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure it out:
1. Just call the code behind function without passing a data for this function like this '`OnClick="SomeFunction"`'.
2. In the code behind the function should appear as the following:

```
Sub SomeFunction(ByVal sender as object, byval e As EnventArgs)
       dim lBtn as LinkButton=directcast(sender, LinkButton)
       sender.PostBackUrl = "http://www.microsoft.com"

       'Do some other stuff

End Sub
```